# webauthn: how can I link my phone to my computer browser

Tags: google-chrome, webauthn

The [web authn](https://webauthn.org/) standard is coming and it works great on my phone.

However when trying on my browser on computer I get

[image: device incompatible]

I would assume we should somehow be able to link our phone with the browser so the phone gets prompted... How can we do this?

A cool and well crafted demo: https://webauthn.me/

edit sep 2019: I also like https://webauthn.io/

Comment: i just found: https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portability is not part of the standard according to the people who created it. I guess it's gonna be useless without being able to use it on different devices. So your out of luck right now.